# Calculating exact volume of an irregular object

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

For an assignment I have to use numerical integration technique to calculate volume with cylindrical surface

> Ω=(x−0.5)^2 +(y−0.5)^2 ≤0.25
>   and height is ln(x+y)

I have used Monte Carlo technique to calculate the volume. But to be sure the answer is correct I want to check the exact volume. I have been searching online on how to do it but couldn't find it.

So the question is, is there a way to calculate exact volume for that object or integral like
this:

[image]

Comment: This site is for *Mathematica* questions.

Comment: is there a way to calculate that volume using Mathematica

Comment: Yes; look up `NIntegrate[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the region of integration using Boole

```
NIntegrate[Abs[Log[x + y]]* Boole[(x - 0.5)^2 + (y - 0.5)^2 <= 0.25], 
  {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}]
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @bill s 
Does that work in mathematica online?

Comment: is there a reason that you used {x, -0.5, 0.5}, {y, -0.5, 0.5}